# Hashmap - cannot infer arguments

Tags: java, stream, hashmap, maps

Hey :) This is my first post and my first approach at streams! I am trying to learn it by myself, but since its a new style of programming Im having a tough time :D

## **So here's my problem:**

In the following Method I have a Map of **<Long, Ingredient>** as parameter.
(Ingredient has the String Attribute "name".)

I want to return an inverted Map of **<String, Long>**.
(The string being the Attribute "name" of the class Ingredient.)

### Here is my solution using a for-loop (which worked)

```
public static Map<String, Long> focusOnNameAndInvert(Map<Long, Ingredient> articles) {
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>(articles.values().stream().map(Ingredient::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    ArrayList<Long> keyList = new ArrayList<>(articles.keySet());

    Map<String, Long> nameAndInvertedMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<nameList.size(); i++){
        nameAndInvertedMap.put(nameList.get(i), keyList.get(i));
    }

    return nameAndInvertedMap;
}
```

### Here is my approach on using streams (which I need help with)

The "<>" on the right side of initializing the HashMap is red underlined and says **"Cannot infer arguments"** (Using IntelliJ)

```
public static Map<String, Long> focusOnNameAndInvert(Map<Long, Ingredient> articles) {
    Map<String, Long> nameAndInvertedMap =  new HashMap<>(
            articles.values().stream().map(Ingredient::getName),
            articles.keySet().stream().map(articles::get));


    return nameAndInvertedMap;
}
```

Thank you for all input, tips, critique and especially for your time!
Wishing you all a nice day :-)

Comment: The specific issue you describe in the title of the question happens because you're creating two streams (the return of both .map() operations) and passing them to an hypothetical constructor of HashMap taking these two arguments, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Which `HashMap` constructor are you trying to use there?

Comment: Im trying to use the (K,V) constructor.

Comment: Now of course, what you're asking is definitely possible using streams, but not like you're doing. I can't test it on an IDE but should look something like this: `Map<String, Long> nameAndInvertedMap = articles.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getValue().getName(), Map.Entry::getKey));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is not actually doing what you hoped. As you can see from the compiler error, there is no `HashMap` constructor which accepts a `List` of keys and a `List` of values. Besides, even if it did, you're streaming the given `Map` (twice), then trying to swap the keys and the values in different streams and finally not even collecting the values of your streams. Streams are pipelines of operations lazily evaluated, if you do not add a terminal operation they are not even executed.

Here there is an official Oracle's tutorial which sums up quite good the concept of streams and how they work:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#laziness

You can write what your method by streaming the entries of the given map and then collect them with the `collect(Collectors.toMap())` terminal operation where each `Ingredient`'s name is mapped as the key while the long keys as their value.

```
public static Map<String, Long> focusOnNameAndInvert(Map<Long, Ingredient> articles) {
    return articles.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getValue().getName(), entry -> entry.getKey()));
}
```

Note that collecting the entries with the 2 parameters version of the method `toMap()` does not work if there are multiple keys, i.e. duplicate ingredient names in your case. The 3 parameters version of the method should be preferred as it allows handling the case of colliding keys (multiple same keys mapping different values). Possible implementations could be: discarding a value over the other, summing the values and so on.

Here is a possible implementation where just one of the two values is maintained.

```
public static Map<String, Long> focusOnNameAndInvert(Map<Long, Ingredient> articles) {
        return articles.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getValue().getName(), entry -> entry.getKey(), (longVal1, longVal2) -> longVal1));
    }
```

Comment: Note: does not work if entry values with duplicate `Long` value exists (a case for the 3-argument `toMap()`)

Comment: @user16320675 true, I'll make sure to add that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your stream is incorrect. Should be something like this:

```java
public static Map<String, Long> focusOnNameAndInvert(Map<Long, Ingredient> articles) {
  return articles.entrySet().stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getValue().getName(), Map.Entry::getKey));
}
```